# Why isn't Network.enable found?

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol

Here's my messages received via WebSocket.  When I send this message:

```
{ id: 3, method: 'Network.enable' }
```

... it replies with:

```
{ id: 3, error: { code: -32601, message: "'Network.enable' wasn't found" } }
```

It says the same for `'Page.navigate'` as well.

```js
{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"1541d58d-c591-4a88-9e53-852b43ad9151","type":"browser","title":"","url":"","attached":true,"canAccessOpener":false}}}
{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"53D6E4E3FF62F8365364C9C252B99EA1","type":"background_page","title":"Chrome Media Router","url":"chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/_generated_background_page.html","attached":false,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"}}}
{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"885AA252B844C7B4FEC9F5AA2174CC76","type":"page","title":"","url":"https://www.websocket.org/echo.html","attached":false,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"}}}
{"id":1,"result":{}}
{"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"53D6E4E3FF62F8365364C9C252B99EA1","type":"background_page","title":"Chrome Media Router","url":"chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/_generated_background_page.html","attached":false,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"}}}
{"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"885AA252B844C7B4FEC9F5AA2174CC76","type":"page","title":"","url":"https://www.websocket.org/echo.html","attached":true,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"}}}
{"method":"Target.attachedToTarget","params":{"sessionId":"F9B5F64C1027EDFD4C1C20B827D40CF0","targetInfo":{"targetId":"885AA252B844C7B4FEC9F5AA2174CC76","type":"page","title":"","url":"https://www.websocket.org/echo.html","attached":true,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"},"waitingForDebugger":false}}
{"id":2,"result":{"sessionId":"F9B5F64C1027EDFD4C1C20B827D40CF0"}}
{"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"885AA252B844C7B4FEC9F5AA2174CC76","type":"page","title":"https://www.websocket.org/echo.html","url":"https://www.websocket.org/echo.html","attached":true,"canAccessOpener":false,"browserContextId":"FA3F0A2AA7B4498D28B9CD859D95FBB4"}}}
{"id":3,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Network.enable' wasn't found"}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the session first, if you are using java / selenium the code is: devTools.createSession();

Answer (score 2):

before activate that , you need to create session in the devTools
you can activate with this way

```
    DevTools chromeDevTools = chromeDriver.getDevTools();
    chromeDevTools.createSession();
```

And after that you can do whatever you want

thank's

Answer (score 0):

When using chrome devtools ws, you need to use a sessionId to enable Network on a page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).